# How to run current python script without locking Vim?

Tags: python, windows, vim

To run current Python script/file in Vim I use this command:

```
:!python %
```

The problem is that this locks Vim so I can't look at or edit files in Vim until I close the cmd window.

This is for Windows.

How can I run the Python-script without locking the current script/file in Vim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Unix, you would append `&` to the command (a shell feature); Windows Vim has the special `:!start` command for that.

```
:!start python %
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, if your script don't have output, or stream output to file

```
:!python % &
```

pressing enter should return you to vim

Comment: Still the same problem and also the & character causes and error message.

Comment: It seems like on windows it not work, according this link http://superuser.com/questions/198525/how-can-i-execute-a-windows-command-line-in-background `:!START \B python %` should work

Answer (score 1):

Vim has problems running things asynchronously, there's a few ways around this, but the easiest for you would be to grab a plugin that can do it for you.

Try tpope's Dispatch: https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch

Then you can run `:Start! python %` to run it in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Or simply execute `pyf %` or map it to some key, for instance `map <F8> pyf %<CR>`

Answer (score 0):

Since version 8.0, if your Vim was compiled with `+terminal` feature, you can see the output of your script in a separate window while editing other files.

```
:ter python %
```

or

```
:%ter python
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am usually using vim in a tmux window, split horizontally in two, for this and use the following mapping, assuming that I want to run the python script in the lower pane (pane number 1),

```
nnoremap ,s :execute '!tmux send-keys -t 1 ''python ' . expand('%:p') .' '' Enter '<cr>
```

If you now press `,s`, this will execute your script in pane 1